# Have a PhD, Hold a PhD or Be a PhD?

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct?

> Have a PhD, Hold a PhD or Be a PhD?

Like if I want to talk about someone which one shall I use?

> My wife is a PhD.

Or

> My wife has a PhD.

or

> My wife holds a PhD.

Comment: All are correct, in my opinion... "My wife is a PHD" - meaning she carries the title of "Doctor" in academic circles. "My wife has a PHD" -  meaning he has a doctorate degree. "My wife holds a PHD degree" is also correct as the degree was awarded to her

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common usage is b) My wife has a PhD.

> My wife is a PhD.

Incorrect, in order to use the verb "to be" where your wife is the subject, the object of the sentence must be something that your wife can be.  A Doctorate is an award, a qualification or a certificate, your wife cannot be an award.  The correct grammar would be "the highest attainment in the field is a PhD"

> My wife has a PhD.

Correct, this is commonly used.  The subject of the sentence has in their possession a scroll declaring that they have earned a doctorate.

> My wife holds a PhD.

Can be used but I haven't heard anyone say this.  Technically correct, the subject can physically hold an award, your wife could also cherish the PhD, be proud of the PhD or earn the PhD.

If however you wish to convey the subjects level of attainment, then it is more common to say that your wife has a PhD in [whatever the field of study is].

Comment: Actually, Google Ngrams suggests that they're all pretty comparable in usage: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+a+PhD%2Cholds+a+PhD%2Cis+a+PhD&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20a%20PhD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cholds%20a%20PhD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20PhD%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @stangdon Any chance "is a PhD" is common simply because it's part of "...is a PhD _student_"?

Comment: @miltonaut - true, absolutely possible.  Ngrams is a crude tool sometimes!

Comment: PhD means Doctor of Philosophy (from *Philosophiae Doctor*) which can refer to both [the degree and the person who holds the degree](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/phd), so it is correct to say that someone ***is** a PhD*. That said, I agree that this form is less common. By adding a space and an asterisk after each search term, the ngram cited by @stangdon can be extended to show that *is a PhD* is usually, though not always, qualifying another word, as miltonaut suggests (most often *candidate* or *student*).

Comment: Adding support to @1006a's comment. Also the Oxford English Dictionary, entry *P*, defines "PhD" as "Doctor of Philosophy, Doctorate of philosophy". So "to be a PhD" and "to have a PhD" are both correct. This is also clear from its appositive use in many citations such as "J. C. Maxwell, Ph.D.", which means "J. C. Maxwell, Doctor of Philosophy".